# Entire function bounded sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function  such that $|f(1/n)|\leq 1/n^{3/2}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then show that $\{n^2f(1/n)\}$ is bounded.

To show that $\{n^2f(1/n)\}$ is bounded, we need $M>0$ such that $|n^2f(1/n)|\leq M$ equivalently $|f(1/n)|\leq M/n^2$.

We have $|f(1/n)|\leq 1/n^{3/2}$ and we want to prove $|f(1/n)|\leq M/n^2$..

I could not think of any method..

Suggest some hints..

EDIT : Suppose it is unbounded, given $M>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n^2 f(1/n)|>M$ in particular, for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $n_i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(1/n_i)|\geq i/n_i^2$..

I do not see what property of analytic function i have to use in this case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f$ has a zero at $0$.  What can you say about its order?

Comment: We  have $1/n\rightarrow 0$.. As $f$ is continuous $f(1/n)\mapsto f(0)$ as $|f(1/n)|\leq 1/n^{3/2}$ we have $f(1/n)\mapsto 0$.. So, $f(0)=0$... I could not think any thing about the order...

Comment: Please give one more hint

Comment: Unless $f$ is constant, the order is a positive integer.  If it were $1$, we would have $|f(1/n)| \sim \ldots$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Suppose it is of order $1$ then we have $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$ and $a_1\neq 0$.. $f(1/n)\rightarrow 0$ only..

Comment: But then you wouldn't have $|f(1/n)| \le 1/n^{3/2}$.

Comment: $|f(1/n)|=(1/n)|a_1+a_2(1/n)+\cdots|$ with $|f(1/n)|\leq 1/n^{3/2}$ implies $|a_1+a_2(1/n)+\cdots|\leq 1/n^{1/2}$.. I dont know how to understand this.... Special case is when $a_i=1$ for all $i$ then we need to have $|1+(1/n)+\cdots|\leq 1/n^{1/2}$ which is clearly not possible as $1+(1/n)+\cdots=\frac{n}{n-1}$.. This is certainly not less than $1/n^{1/2}$ as this would imply $n^3<(n-1)^2$ which is not true.. could not see the same for general case

Comment: When $f(z)$ has a zero of first order at $0$, $0 \ne f'(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} $.  But $\left|\frac{f(1/n)}{1/n}\right| \le \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \to 0$.

Comment: Ok.. So, we have $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}{\infty}a_n z^n$.. As $f(0)=0$ we have $a_0=0$.. As you have said $a_1=0$. So, $f(z)=a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots$... $n^2f(1/n)=a_2+a_3(1/n)+a_4(1/n^2)+\cdots$... talking modulus, we have $$|n^2f(1/n)|=|a_2+a_3(1/n)+\cdots|\leq |a_2+a_3+\cdots|=|f(1)|$$Thus, $(n^2f(1/n))$ is bounded..

Comment: Is my justification correct? I am a bit doubtful...

Comment: $f(x)/x^2 = a_2 + a_3 x + \ldots$ converges for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, so is analytic in that neighbourhood, and in particular $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x^2 = a_2$.  Now take $x = 1/n$.